# Only "New Folder" in context menu in the Public folder on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, context-menu

The Public folder in Windows 7 (*C:\Users\Public*) can be written to without being an Administrator, but why doesn't the "New" context menu display options such as **New Text Document**?

[image]

Comment: What are the other options that you want to include when you right-click under the C:\Users\Public folder?

Comment: Go to `Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network and Sharing Center\Advanced sharing settings`, Public branch, and verify that everything is "On". Also in `C:\Users`, right-click Public, then Properties, and list the permission in the Security tab. For good measures, you might run [sfc /scannow](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The items are missing from the "New" context menu in the `C:\Users\Public` folder because you do not have the NTFS permissions `Write Attributes` and `Write Extended Attributes` to that folder.

If you want the full list of items on the "New" menu, grant these two permissions on the Public folder to your user account or a group of which you're a member, as shown here:
[image]

---

#### Additional details

You already have permissions to create files and folders in the Public folder as granted via implicit membership in the `INTERACTIVE` special identity.  Per [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd637754.aspx):

> Any user logged on to the local system has the Interactive identity.

By default in Windows 7 the `INTERACTIVE` special identity is granted permission to create new folders **and files** in the `C:\Users\Public` as shown here:

[image]

To prove to yourself you indeed have permission to create files in the Public folder, do the following:

1. Open a Command Prompt (not as Administrator)
2. Type `CD C:\Users\Public` then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Type `COPY CON NewFile.txt` then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Type `Hello world` then press <kbd>F6</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>
5. Close Command Prompt and browse to the Public folder.  Observe the **NewFile.txt** that you created.

Comment: I have the same problem with another folder. With just `Create Files`, I can directly save files into the folder from applications like Notepad. It's only the `New > File` menu options that are missing. Why does it need `Write Attributes` for this?

Comment: @Locutus I honestly don't know why Explorer behaves this way.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your account is not a local admin so you only have the "Folder" option on the "New" context-menu.  If your user account is a local admin, then the full "New" context-menu will be available.  You can otherwise follow the answer from @twisty and manually grant the permission to see it.

Microsoft generally doesn't really want you to create files in the root of the public folder so it doesn't become a dumping ground.  They have provided subfolders for this purpose.  If you try the same thing in any the subfolders from any account, you will get your normal New document context menu.

Comment: False. I have the same New menu on Public as on every other folder.

Comment: @harrymc - so when you are in C:\Users\Public you can right-click, choose New and you get more than just "Folder" in the context-menu?

Comment: Yes. The proof : http://i.stack.imgur.com/Pm2QJ.jpg.

Comment: @harrymc And you are using Windows 7 without having modified the permissions?

Comment: Yes. I never modify the permissions of special Windows folders on C: because the results are unpredictable, as the poster found out. Are you having the same problem?

Comment: Yes.  I have access to lots of desktops.  I have just checked a bunch and found if the user is a local admin, then the full "New" context-menu is available.  If they are not a local admin, then only the "Folder" option is available under the New context-menu.   In my defence, my original comment still stands.  Local admins can do a lot more than the average user and MS don't want average users dumping stuff in C:\Users\Public. I feel the down vote is undeserved.

Comment: The downvote is not mine, and I am in fact local admin, so your comment is probably correct. You should have put that info into your answer, because as it is it seems rather baseless. Rewrite your answer and you will have my upvote.

Comment: +1 Upvoted, and good luck in our forum. Writing clear and complete answers is important to avoid downvotes.

Comment: @joehanna Do you have UAC enabled on your computer where you get the full "New" context menu as Admin? Also, note that with default permissions in place *all* logged on users have sufficient rights to create files in the Public folder. As noted in my answer the lack of "New" items isn't due to not having permission to create said items.

Comment: @Twisty, UAC was disabled when logged in as admin.  I set it on, rebooted and found the full New menu was no longer available to the admin user.

Comment: That's what I expected. Without UAC you get the permissions granted to the `Administrators` group, which is Full Control. However, with UAC in effect, even if you're logged in as an admin, you only get those permissions granted to the `Interactive` identity which is lacking the two "Write Attributes" permissions.

Comment: All bets are off when you're admin and UAC is disabled

Comment: You are correct. UAC can make things like this difficult to sort out. I forgot to take into account the fact that when actually logged in with the built-in Administrator account UAC is not in effect, even if it's enable on the machine. What a maze!