# Windows Explorer's "New > File" menu won't display without "Write Attributes" permission for the folder

Tags: permissions, windows-explorer, filesystems, ntfs

In Windows Explorer, a folder's context menu only displays the `New > File` options if the `Write Attributes` permission has been granted on the folder. However when using another application such as Notepad, I am able to save new files in the folder with just the `Create Files` permission.

Why does Windows Explorer also need `Write Attributes` for the folder just to show the `New > File` list?

The folder owner is `Administrators`.

`Administrators` and `SYSTEM` have `Full Control` for `This Folder, Subfolders & Files`.

`Users` have `Read & Execute` for `This Folder, Subfolders & Files`.

`Authenticated Users` have `Create Files` and `Create Folders` for `This Folder Only`.

`CREATOR OWNER` has `Full Control` for `Subfolders & Files`.

Comment: Any app can create files successfully because of the `Authenticated Users` permissions. It's only the `New > File` menu options that aren't showing. If I grant `Write Attributes` to `Authenticated Users` for `This Folder Only`, then they show up.

Comment: I'm using the latest Windows 10 Anniversary update. It's a newly formatted drive with default permissions. The permissions above are explicitly set on one folder without inheritance. Obviously UAC needs to be enabled and the owner needs to be `Administrators` (not `Administrator` or your user account) for this to be reproduced.

Comment: Same problem but no explanation why.
http://superuser.com/questions/892859/only-new-folder-in-context-menu-in-the-public-folder-on-windows-7